# Django Ajax Not Found "url"

Tags: django, ajax

i am trying to use ajax with django:

```
 $('.btnMyc').click(function() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "/getpic",
            data: {
                username: document.getElementById("usernameid").value
            },
```

urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = [
path('', views.vscomain, name="vscomain"),
path('getpic',views.send_pic,name="getpic"),
```

]

and there is a function names send_pic in views.py but when i type username and click it i get this error:

> Not Found: /getpic
> [21/Sep/2021 14:00:59] "GET /getpic?username=sfdgl HTTP/1.1" 404 2400

views.py:

```
def send_pic(request):
    try:
            username=request.GET.dict()["username"]     
            user=vsco(username) 
            link=user.find_link()
            return render(request,"vsco.html" ,{'vscolink':link})
   except:
            link="https://cdn.freelogovectors.net/wp-content/uploads/2012/04/warning.png"
            return JsonResponse({'vscolink':'link'})
```

Comment: Can you share your views.py?

Comment: i just shared it

Comment: As far as I understand, you try to access username specific pages for each user. Right? I think we need a little clarification there.

Answer (score 0):

**To write Django like variables in JavaScript :**

**If your JavaScript is on the same file with your html :**
`let url_post = "{% url 'getpic' %}"` and in ajax : `url: url_post`.

**If your JavaScript is on a external file :**
Retrieve the value on a `<script>` tag like this :
`<script>let value = "{{django_value}}" or let value2 = "{% url 'django_url_name' %}"</script>`

And then call your external file like this:
`<script src="{% static 'path/to/external_file.js' %}"> ... </script>`
Don't forget the `{% load static %}` at the top of your template file.

Comment: i did it and got this error again:     Not Found: /vsco-profil-buyutucu/undefined
[21/Sep/2021 14:35:34] "GET /vsco-profil-buyutucu/undefined HTTP/1.1" 404 2710